# Right outer join using eager loading EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

I have two tables `ads` and categories for a classifieds app.

One category can have many ads.

I like to know how to get all the categories where they have ads or not. Right outer join using eager loading using `.include`

**I like the example using lambda expression**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by combination of "right outer join" and "eager loading". Eager loading on collection navigation property performs internally left outer join and will return the category regardless of having ads or not. This is pretty standard EF behavior. `var result = db.Categories.Include(c => c.Ads).ToList();`

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for comment. So what you are saying is that we cannot create `Right outer joing` using eager loading?

Comment: it's just the matter of order of objects. Try starting from your *right* object instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code you tried. Check [how to post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information.

If I understand correctly you can do something like this:

```
var result = dbContext.Categories.GroupJoin(dbContext.Ads, 
                cat => cat.Id, 
                ad => ad.CategoryId, 
                (cat, ads) => new { Category = cat, Ads = ads.DefaultIfEmpty() });
```

This will translate to a `LEFT JOIN` between the categories and ads.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. You just want to include the ads when you fetch the categories? That's easy enough if you have a navigation property on Categories. Just do this:

```
  yourDbContext.Set<Categories>().Include(x => x.Ads)
```

If you do not have a navigation property on Categories i recommend adding one.

Comment: Is there a way to perform inner join using eager loading?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you want your result to be in this case? If i'm not mistaken the code above actually translates to an inner join in sql. It will populate the navigation property on Categories. If no match, the collection will be empty.